# ShowOptionDialog cancel option doesn't work

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a GUI for my program. This particular GUI uses a JOptionsPane with a showOptionDialog. I have added a panel to that OptionsPane that has some action listeners as well as two lists and some other things, that really doesn't matter for this question though.

Quite simply I want my showOptionDialog to perform some action when the user clicks the "cancel" button. (It will basically end the program but it must be done in a certain way). Right now when the user clicks "cancel" the program continues as if the user just ended that dialog but no action is taken. I am trying to change a variable if they click cancel which will prevent the rest of the program from running. I tested with a System.out.println to see if my value was really being changed and I found that the step wasn't occurring at all. So I would like to know based upon this code what I am doing wrong. What do I need to do to make the code run correctly when the user clicks cancel?

I do not have more code to show as my program is very large and it is impossible for me to isolate this situation.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
public static void displayGUI(){

        int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, getPanel(),"JOptionPane Example : ", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new String[]{"Confirm","Create Return"}, "default");

        if(result == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
            initialScreenDecisions="NONE";
            MainWriter.finishedCounter=true;
            System.out.println(MainWriter.finishedCounter);
            while(MainWriter.entryDetails.size()>0){
                MainWriter.entryDetails.remove(0);
            }
            while(output.size()>0){
                output.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

*This part of the code isn't being executed, even if the user selects cancel:

```
if(result == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
            initialScreenDecisions="NONE";
            MainWriter.finishedCounter=true;
            System.out.println(MainWriter.finishedCounter);
            while(MainWriter.entryDetails.size()>0){
                MainWriter.entryDetails.remove(0);
            }
            while(output.size()>0){
                output.remove(0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value of `result` to see what's actually returned?

Comment: @steven35 While that's good advice on its surface, `result` is an int value that is used as an enum that needs to be compared with various `JOptionPane` constants, which makes attaching any obvious meaning to its value somewhat difficult. (You have to root through the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#javax.swing.JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) to find its associated value). The lack of actual enums for `JOptionPane` is one of my biggest complaints about an otherwise useful class.

Comment: "result" is set to the index of the button clicked, where the buttons are created from the object array passed in (in this case, "Confirm" and "Create Return").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Question:
`*This part of the code isn't being executed, even if the user selects cancel:`

Try The `integer` value that is returned from the `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()`. `0` Is returned if `OK` is selected and `1` is returned if `Cancel` is selected.

Modify your `code` as follows:

```
if(result == 1){
        initialScreenDecisions="NONE";
        MainWriter.finishedCounter=true;
        System.out.println(MainWriter.finishedCounter);
        while(MainWriter.entryDetails.size()>0){
            MainWriter.entryDetails.remove(0);
        }
        while(output.size()>0){
            output.remove(0);
        }
    }
```

Let me Know, If this doesn't Helps you!!!

Comment: If this Answer helps you then upvote and accept the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you very much!

That solved my problem instantly. Very helpful now I don't have to keep fighting with such a simple issue, very frustrating when I can use action listeners and double lists but can't get something simple to work but it's perfect now!

Comment: The OP's code does not have an "OK" button or a "Cancel" button. He specifies the buttons to be "Confirm" and "Create Return". The fourth argument (in his case, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION) is used only to determine what icon to display on the left side of the JOptionPane.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling JOptionPane to create two buttons ("Confirm" and "Create Return"), and then telling it the default button is "default" but you don't have a button with text "default". You also don't have a Cancel". The return value will be 0 if the uses picks "Confirm", or 1 if the user picks "Create Return", or CLOSED_OPTION if the user just closes the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the JavaDocs for [`JOptionPane.showOptionDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)), it tells you

> Returns:
>      an integer indicating the option chosen by the user, or
>   CLOSED_OPTION if the user closed the dialog

This is the index of the `options` array you passed to the method.  In this case `new String[]{"Confirm","Create Return"}`

So a return value of `0` will mean `Confirm` was selected and `1` will mean `Create Return` was selected (or `JOptionPane.CLOSE_OPTION` if the user closed the window)

Answer (score 0):

When assigning `result` a value you are using `JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION` but in the if condition you are checking for `JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION`